# MVVM with Repository/Firestore - Where is the best place to store different queried arrays from a single collection?

Tags: firebase, mvvm, swiftui, repository-pattern

I am building a ToDo List App using Firestore based on this [google tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4RUeW5rUcww), with a SwiftUI app using an MVVM/repository pattern, that uses one load query to find all tasks ("actions"), and I'm trying to set it up so I can have multiple date-based queries (e.g. display dates for today, for next week, possibly on the same screen)

The current version I'm working on has one single "loadData" function in the repository that is saved to a single published "actions" variable, and called when this is initialized.

```
class ActionRepository: ObservableObject, ActionStoreType {
    
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    @Published var actions = [Action]()
    
    init() {
        loadData()
    }
    
    func loadData() {
        let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        
        db.collection("action")
            .order(by: "createdTime")
            .whereField("userId", isEqualTo: userId!)
            .addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
                if let querySnapshot = querySnapshot {
                    self.actions = querySnapshot.documents.compactMap { document in
                        do {
                            let x = try document.data(as: Action.self)
                            return x
                        }
                        catch {
                            print(error)
                        }
                        return nil
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

My view model just calls the repository with no parameters.

```
class ActionListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var actionRepository = ActionRepository()
    @Published var actionCellViewModels = [ActionCellViewModel]()
    
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init() {
        actionRepository.$actions.map { actions in
            actions.map { action in
                ActionCellViewModel(action: action)
            }
        }
        .assign(to: \.actionCellViewModels, on: self)
        .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
```

I want to add a function to load data by date that I can call as many times as I want:

```
    func loadMyDataByDate2(from startDate: Date, to endDate: Date? = nil) {
        let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        let initialDate = startDate
        var finalDate: Date
        
        if endDate == nil {
            finalDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: initialDate)!
        } else {
            finalDate = endDate!
        }
        
        db.collection("action")
            .order(by: "createdTime")
            .whereField("userId", isEqualTo: userId!)
            .whereField("startDate", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: initialDate)
            .whereField("startDate", isLessThanOrEqualTo: finalDate)
            .addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
                if let querySnapshot = querySnapshot {
                    self.actions = querySnapshot.documents.compactMap { document in
                        do {
                            let x = try document.data(as: Action.self)
                            return x
                        }
                        catch {
                            print(error)
                        }
                        return nil
                    }
                }
            }
```

But I don't know the best way to do this. If I want my view model to have three lists of tasks: one for today, one for the rest of the week, and one for next week, what would be the best way to do this?

Should I create separate variables in the repository or the View Model to store these different lists of actions?
Or add date variables for the repository so I call multiple instances of it within the View Model?

I just want to make sure I'm not going down an unwise path with how I start building this out.

Comment: Seeing no-one has answered this in the past couple of days, here is a quick suggestion: fetch the data into a published property, just like you did. As it sounds your other lists are filtered subsets of this main list, you should be able to add a couple of Combine pipelines to perform the filtering and assign the result to some other published properties. LMK if this helps, I'm happy to sketch a more detailed solution as an answer.

Comment: @PeterFriese thank you for your response! I ended up doing something like what you suggested, putting my other filtered lists directly in the ViewModel. This seems to be working fine right now. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear you were able to resolve this :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing something based on Peter's suggestion. I am getting all these filtered lists in my ViewModel. Instead of taking from the repository and storing them all in one ActionCellViewModel property, I created four different ActionCellViewModel properties.

I have four different functions in my initializer code now, and each one takes the list of actions, filters it based on date and completion status, and assigns it to the appropriate CellViewModel property for use in my view.

```
class ActionListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var actionRepository: ActionStoreType
    
    @Published var baseDateActionCellViewModels = [ActionCellViewModel]()
    @Published var baseDateWeekActionCellViewModels = [ActionCellViewModel]()
    @Published var previousActionCellViewModels = [ActionCellViewModel]()
    @Published var futureActionCellViewModels = [ActionCellViewModel]()
    
    @Published var baseDate: Date = Date()
    @Published var hideCompleted: Bool = true
    @Published var baseDateIsEndOfWeek: Bool = false
    
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    // MARK: Initializers
    
    // Default initializer for production code.
    init() {
        self.actionRepository = ActionRepository()
        self.baseDateIsEndOfWeek = isDateEndOfWeek(date: self.baseDate, weekEnd: self.baseDate.endOfWeekDate(weekStart: .sat))
        
        loadPastActions()
        loadBaseActions()
        loadWeekTasks()
        loadFutureActions()
    }
    
    
    // MARK: Functions for initializing the main groups of actions for the Homepage.
    
    
    func isDateEndOfWeek(date currentDate: Date, weekEnd endOfWeekDate: Date) -> Bool {

        if currentDate == endOfWeekDate {
            print("Current Date: \(currentDate) and endOfWeekDate: \(endOfWeekDate) are the same!")
            return true
        } else {
            print("The current date of \(currentDate) is not the end of the week (\(endOfWeekDate))")
            return false
        }
    }
    
    ///The loadPastActions function takes the published actions list from the repository, and pulls a list of actions from before the base date. (It hides completed actions by default, but this is impacted by the viewModel's "hideCompleted" parameter.
    ///
    ///- returns: Assigns a list of actions from prior to the base date to the pastActionCellViewModels published property in the viewModel.
    func loadPastActions() {
        self.actionRepository.actionsPublisher.map { actions in
            actions.filter { action in
                action.beforeDate(self.baseDate) && action.showIfIncomplete(onlyIncomplete: self.hideCompleted)
            }
            .map { action in
                ActionCellViewModel(action: action)
            }
        }
        .assign(to: \.previousActionCellViewModels, on: self)
        .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
    
    ///The loadBaseActions function takes the published actions list from the repository, and pulls a list of actions from the base date. (It hides completed actions by default, but this is impacted by the viewModel's "hideCompleted" parameter.
    ///
    ///- returns: Assigns a list of actions from the base date to the viewModel's baseDateActionCellViewModels property.
    func loadBaseActions() {
        self.actionRepository.actionsPublisher.map { actions in
            actions.filter { action in
                action.inDateRange(from: self.baseDate, to: self.baseDate) && action.showIfIncomplete(onlyIncomplete: self.hideCompleted)
            }
            .map { action in
                ActionCellViewModel(action: action)
            }
        }
        .assign(to: \.baseDateActionCellViewModels, on: self)
        .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
    
    /// The loadWeekActions takes the published actions list for the current user from the repository, and pulls a list of actions either from remainder of the current week (if not the end of the week), or from next week, if it's the last day of the week.
    ///
    ///- returns: Assigns a list of actions from the rest of this week or the next week to the viewModel's baseDateWeekActionCellViewModels property.
    func loadWeekTasks() {
        let startDate: Date = self.baseDate.tomorrowDate()
        print("Start date is \(startDate) and the end of that week is \(startDate.endOfWeekDate(weekStart: .sat))")
        
        self.actionRepository.actionsPublisher.map { actions in
            actions.filter { action in
                action.inDateRange(from: startDate, to: startDate.endOfWeekDate(weekStart: .sat)) && action.showIfIncomplete(onlyIncomplete: self.hideCompleted)
            }
            .map { action in
                ActionCellViewModel(action: action)
            }
        }
        .assign(to: \.baseDateWeekActionCellViewModels, on: self)
        .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
    
    /// The loadFutureActions function takes the published actions list for the current user from the repository, and pulls a list of actions from after the week tasks.
    ///
    ///- returns: Assigns a list of actions from the future (beyond this week or next, depending on whether the baseDate is the end of the week) to the futureActionCellViewModels property in the viewModel.
    func loadFutureActions() {
        let startAfter: Date = baseDate.tomorrowDate().endOfWeekDate(weekStart: .sat)
        
        self.actionRepository.actionsPublisher.map { actions in
            actions.filter { action in
                action.afterDate(startAfter) && action.showIfIncomplete(onlyIncomplete: self.hideCompleted)
            }
            .map { action in
                ActionCellViewModel(action: action)
            }
        }
        .assign(to: \.futureActionCellViewModels, on: self)
        .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
```

Comment: Curious, why expose the repositories?

Comment: I didn't have any other layers that this data was stored in - it was direct from the repository. But the type `ActionStoreType` is a protocol type so it could be easily replaced with a mock in unit testing. I didn't see a need for any other layers of abstraction between.